# how to compare properties of two objects

Tags: javascript, object

```
var arr = [{'a':'daina', 'z':12},{'b':'john', 'y':22}, {'c':'alan','z':30}];
var arr2 = [{'c':'john', 'z':62}, {'d':'alana','s':32},  {'e':'mac','t':42}];
var finalArray = [];
for(var key2 in arr) {
  console.log(arr[key2]);
}
function compareKeys(arr,arr2){
  for(var key1 in arr2){
    for(var key in arr){
      if(key1 === key){
        finalArray = arr.splice(key,1);
      }
    }
  }
  for(var key in finalArray) {
    console.log(finalArray[key]);
  }
}
compareKeys(arr,arr2);
```

I am not getting what is wrong with the code. I want to remove 'c' property from 'arr' after comparing both 'arr' and 'arr2'. The 'c' property is same in both arrays so I want to remove it in my output. The output returned by the function should be `{'a':'daina', 'z':12},{'b':'john', 'y':22}`

Can anyone help me in comparing the properties of objects?

Comment: in arra2 c object is {'c':'john', 'z':62} and in arr it is {'c':'alan','z':30}

Comment: they both are not same

Comment: yeah but It does not matter what the value are,  the properties name should not be same.

Comment: but the z property also exists in multiple objects in both arrays. What is the condition to keep it.

Comment: I'm just curious, do you really write code with random indentation, and if so, how do you read it? Is it really that hard to indent properly? Your editor probably has a command to do that for you.

Comment: *I want to remove 'c' property from 'arr'*. `arr` does not have a `c` property; it contains an object which includes the `c` property. Do you mean you want to remove all objects which have any property in common with any of the objects in `arr2`?

Comment: yes. I want to display only those objets in arr which are not common with arr2

Comment: Your question is still quite ambiguous.  Is this what your want:  "I want a list of all those elements of `arr` excluding those for which there is an element of `arr2` with a matching set of keys."?  Do we exclude ` {'c':'alan','z':30}` because _both_ 'c' and 'z' are included, or is there something special about 'c'?

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing up arrays, objects, keys and values here.

You should read the variables `arr` and `arr2` as

```
arr[0] = {'a':'daina', 'z':12}
arr[1] = {'b':'john', 'y':22}
arr[2] = {'c':'alan','z':30}]

and

arr2[0] = {'c':'john', 'z':62}
arr2[1] = {'d':'alana','s':32}
arr2[2] = {'e':'mac','t':42}
```

so the **keys** of both arrays are 0, 1 and 2, and the **values** are objects.

In your nested loop

```
for(var key1 in arr2){
for(var key in arr){
    if(key1 === key){
      ....
}}}
```

you basically are comparing:

```
key === key1
  0 === 0    (true)
  0 === 1    (false)
  0 === 2    (false)
etc.
```

and not the values.
You should compare `arr[key] === arr2[key1]` to compare the values. Sadly you cannot compare two objects just like that.

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068834/object-comparison-in-javascript). You could either use one of the answers from that to compare the objects, or rethink your data design.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing two object like below

```
 if(arr2[key1] === arr[key])
```

can you try to compare like below

```
JSON.stringify(obj1) === JSON.stringify(obj2)
```